# When setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod is set for a long time and the beacon is turned off / on, a large amount of Range events are fired

Tags: ibeacon-android

The activity is used by the foreground service.

BeaconManager is used as a foreground in that service.

Library version is 2.16.2

***The settings are as follows***

```
g_beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

g_beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(8000);
g_beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(1100);

g_beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
g_beaconManager.bind(this);

g_region = new Region("iBeacon", null, null, null);

g_beaconManager.setRegionStatePersistenceEnabled(false);

g_beaconManager.setDebug(true);
```

Follow the steps below
① Start the service

② didRangeBeaconsInRegion is fired and information of beacon is acquired

③ Beacon power off

④ After 9.9 seconds, didRangeBeaconsInRegion fired and confirmed that there was no beacon information

⑤ Beacon power ON

⑥didRangeBeaconsInRegion is fired in large quantities, and some without beacon information appear. 
In less than 9.9 seconds.

The log is attached.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1QYd.jpg)

③ goes after 14: 36: 13.266.

⑤ goes after 14: 36: 22.332.

14: 36: 26.372 has a problem

SetForegroundBetweenScanPeriod (4000) did not cause this.

Can you tell me why this happens?

It didn't happen with SetForegroundBetweenScanPeriod (4000) when I checked, but could you tell me if it could happen?

Answer (score 0):

With longer between scan periods, the library uses a filtered  intent-backed Bluetooth scan during the between scan period when no beacons are visible.  This is an optimization intended to provide a quick callback on first beacon detection to wake up your app when it is in the background under default library settings.

This optimization is not intended to be triggered in the case of a foreground service scan with a long between scan period, but it does anyway because there is no logic to prevent it. (This is an unusual usage of the library so the library has not been optimized for such usage.)

If this causes you problems, you might try disabling the behavior with `beaconManager.setAndroidLScanningDisabled(true)`. This will disable scans in the between scan period, but may have other side effects.